# how to display stack trace instead of 500 internal server error on weblogic

Tags: java, angular, weblogic, internal-server-error, http-error

I was working with tomcat 7 and when an exception is thrown the stack trace is shown in the browser.
But now I'm using WebLogic 12 . Occasionally, I'll get the message "Error 500--Internal Server Error" appear in my web browser when something has gone wrong and I have to look in the log files for the stack trace of the exception. How can I get the exception to be output directly to my browser ?

FrontEnd Angular.
BackEnd Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to configure a http filter and intercept the exception then send the message to the frontEnd.
In prod mode we cant show stack trace.

in web.xml file we add this:

```
 <filter>
     <filter-name>msg</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.filters.MSGFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>msg</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32629978)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a custom error page (jsp) and declare it in the web.xml file. For instance  :
`<error-page>   <error-code>500</error-code>   <location>myCustomError500.jsp</location>   </error-page>`
You can specify a jsp or an html page
In your case, create a new JSP. It must have this attribute :
`<%@ page isErrorPage= "true" %>`
Inside your jsp, use the built-in exception object to get the error message :
`<%= exception %>`
For the stack trace :
`exception.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out));`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is that I want to extract Java exception message string from stack trace. And then display the message in an angular modal. when I was working with tomcat I could get the Exception stack trace from http response but when I deployed in Weblogic I get only "500 internal server error" without stack trace.

Comment: i have completed my answer